# Approach to Geographic Location Optimization in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, optimization, location-allocation

My goal is to take a geocoded list of targeted consumers, a shapefile of "regions", and create an optimized number of "district" shapes (a geographic child to or subregion of larger regions). I'd like to ensure districts fit within their parent regions and create the smallest number of districts while maximizing the density of consumers inside of the districts.

Let's call the consumer shapefile `consumer_points`, the region shapefile `office_regions`, and the generated district shapes `office_districts`. The scope is within a single US state.

So far, what I've got:

- Assign consumer to Region and append region to consumer_points using `ST_WITHIN()`
- A `zip_code` shapefile to use as a building block for `districts` (i.e. the most granular assembly shape for a district).
- Assigned consumers to their corresponding zip shape using `ST_WITHIN()`

`consumer_points` now has: person_id, latitude, longitude, zip_assignment, zip_geom, region_assignment, region_geom

`zip_codes` now has: zip_code, zip_geom, region_assignment, region_geom

I'm struggling to figure out the next step or potential solutions.

Comment: I feel like, if districts can be arbitrary in size, the highest density over the smallest number of districts will eventually limit in 'one point per its infinitesimally larger circular proximity'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do clustering on your clients, inside each region. If you want a specific number of districts, you should try `St_ClusterKMeans`, and if you prefer trying to set clustering parameters like distance and density desired you can try `ST_ClusterDBScan`.

Once you have your clusters of points (clients), you need to build the district. You can try to do Voronoi polygons. You can use `ST_VoronoiPolygons` on the complete set of points (`ST_Collect` by grouping by region on your points to build a multipoint geom that you pass to `ST_VoronoiPolygons`) and using your region polygon as the `extend_to` parameter. Once you have a polygon for each client, you can `ST_Union` all the polygons on each cluster that you previously computed.

You can also directly use the `ST_VoronoiPolygons` and setting the tolerance parameter to a desired distance that will consider the points closer to that as similar, and avoid doing a separate clustering. It's like a poor version of clustering because it's less configurable but maybe it could answer your problem in a simpler way.